# Método que aumente un atributo

Tags: python

Tengo que realizar un método que aumente un atributo según el parámetro que se le pase. He intentado hacerlo pero no lo consigo. Hasta ahora tengo todo el código listo salvo ese método que no se como hacerlo, se los adjunto:

```
class Dinosaurio:
def __init__(self, color, especie, altura):
    self.color = color
    self.especie = especie
    self.altura = altura
def rugir(self, rugido):
    print("roar")
def crecer(self, altura):
```

El método que tengo que crear es el que se llama crecer, y tiene que hacer que el atributo altura aumente en función del parámetro que se le pase.
Agradecería cualquier ayuda, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Dinosaurio:

    def __init__(self, color, especie, altura):
        self.color = color
        self.especie = especie
        self.altura = altura

    def rugir(self, rugido):
        print("roar")

    def crecer(self, cantidad_a_aumentar):
        self.altura = self.altura + cantidad_a_aumentar


t_rex = Dinosaurio(
    color='red',
    especie='carnivoro?',
    altura=100
)

print(t_rex.altura) # 100
t_rex.crecer(133) # aquí le pasas cuanto quieres que pueda crecer 
print(t_rex.altura) # 233
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!